# Express relationship between the argument and return type by type hints

Tags: python, types

I want to give proper type hints to the following function:

```py
def convert(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        return int(value)
    elif isinstance(value, int):
        return str(value)
    else:
        raise TypeError()
```

This function returns `int` if the argument is `str`, and returns `str` if the argument is `int`. Then how can I give a proper type hint for the return type? I can give a hint like `Union[int, str]`, but I want the return type to be statically determined in a type checker, like Pyright.

As for this example I can split this function into two functions `convert_int_to_str` and `convert_str_to_int`, but I can't in operator overloading. For example, assume I want `Position - Vector` to be `Position` and `Position - Position` to be `Vector`. They are overloads `__sub__(self: Position, other: Position) -> Vector` and `__sub__(self: Position, other: Vector) -> Position`, respectively.

If the argument and return types are the same, maybe `TypeVar` can be used. Is there any way to show this kind of relationship?

Comment: You can use typing.overload

Comment: This seems what I needed. Thanks.